# can someone explain how the controller class works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on spring samples.I have a controller class named UserController2 as follows

```
@Controller
public class UserController2 extends MultiActionController {

   private UserDAO userDAO;

   public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
   }
    @RequestMapping(params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, User user) throws Exception {
       userDAO.saveUser(user);
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:User.htm");
  }

  public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
      ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
      modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
      modelMap.addAttribute("User", new User());
      return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
}
}
```

and i have a jsp page called userForm.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="add.htm" commandName="User" modelAttribute="User">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="password">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="gender">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="gender" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="gender">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="gender" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="country">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="country" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
 </form:form>
```

what actually does the below codes returns

```
  return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
```

and

```
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:User.htm");
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for 
bean name 'User' available as request attribute
```

I searched but i cannot find a proper explanation for modelandview..

Comment: The command name is `User`, and the new User you add to the modelMap is named `user`. Case matters.

Comment: its still showing the same error even after changing it

Comment: Have you also fixed the case in `modelAttribute="User"`?

Comment: yes i did but still the same

Comment: FYI `commandName` and `modelAttribute` both set the same thing.  To eliminate confusion just use modelAttribute and not commandName (think of commandName as deprecated).  Then as @JBNizet says, make sure both use the same case for 'user'.  Generally lowercase names are preferred for model attribs as they are considered variables in the JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

When using the modelAttribute make user that:
1. Your method parameter `user` is annotated with `@ModelAttribute("user")`
2. A method parameter of type `BindingResult` is declared.
 
Also, the annotation parameter value is case sensitive,  and should exactly match the value of the **modelAttribute** you declared in userForm.jsp.